# How to create an array of the last few hours in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, date

I need an array of the last 12 hours in my react app but I only have 2 so far and I'm doing it the most tedious way.

This is my current code that works:

```
class Example extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.now = new Date();
    this.hrAgo = new Date(this.now-3600000).toISOString();
    this.twoHrsAgo = new Date(this.now-2*3600000).toISOString();
    this.state = {
      timeData: [this.twoHrsAgo,this.hrAgo,this.now.toISOString()]
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("timeData: ",this.state.timeData);
  };
/// other function below
```

which displays something like this in my console:

```
["2019-05-08T06:19:41.744Z", "2019-05-08T07:19:41.744Z", "2019-05-08T08:19:41.744Z"]
```

How do I get the last 12 hours in a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an array and try to push as:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.now = new Date();
    let testArr= [];
    for(let i=0;i<12;i++){
    testArr.push(new Date(this.now-i*3600000).toISOString());
    }
    this.state = {
      timeData: testArr
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("timeData: ",this.state.timeData);
  }
```

Sample fiddle : [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/crystalthinker/4x3ajc6k/3/)

Comment: This works! But it's in the wrong direction.. I used unshift() instead of push()

Comment: just change the loop to for(let i=11; i>=0;i--) if you want the reverse

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to create array.
new Array(12) creates empty and fill it with empty string.

```
const now = new Date();
const hourArray = new Array(12).fill("").map((v, i) => (new Date(now - 3600000*i)).toISOStrting())
```

Comment: got an error for this 
```TemperatureChart.jsx:62 Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).toISOStrting is not a function```